# Basel Badischer Bahnhof to Basel SBB train announcement: "Only cross the border with valid documents..." Which border?

Tags: trains, borders, switzerland

On a train from Basel Badischer Bahnhof to Basel SBB there is an automated announcement shortly before departure:

> Cross the border only with valid travel documents and without goods and foreign currency that need to be declared.
>
> Grenzübertritt nur gestattet mit gültigen Reisedokumenten und ohne deklarationspflichtige Waren oder Devisen.

What border is it talking about, though? Both stations are in Basel, Switzerland, aren't they?

Comment: The border at Basel, one presumes.

Comment: It's the Swiss/German border. A fun thing to do is to stand with one leg in each country!

Comment: @WeatherVane not very helpful, if one is in a train that stays _inside_ the city. mdewey gave the correct answer below.

Comment: @WeatherVane There are multiple possible borders at Basel, the urban area includes territory of three countries.

Comment: @Nobody exactly. I didn't get why it is a problem to hear an announcement about border crossing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Despite its location in Switzerland it is an enclave of the EU for customs purposes. The train services are also run by DB (the German operator).

See the wikipedia entry [Basel_Badischer_Bahnhof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_Badischer_Bahnhof) which also gives the history and more detail about which parts are under Swiss rules and which EU.

Comment: Ah so that is it! I wonder why there is no corresponding announcement for Lörrach -> Riehen and Riehen -> Basel Bad Bf.

Comment: Note that likewise, a part of Basel SBB is considered part of the French customs territory, and conversely, part of the Basel-Mulhouse-Freiburg EuroAirport, which is in France, is part of the Swiss customs territory, along with a road from Switzerland to the airport.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Riehen, Niederholz, Trasadingen, Wilchingen-Hallau, Neunkirch, Beringen Bad Bf, Beringerfeld, Neuhausen Bad Bf, Schaffhausen Bad Bf (partly), Herblingen and Thayngen are other German-owned/operated stations in Switzerland, but I don't think they have a similar customs status (not sure).

Comment: @LoremIpsum There aren’t that many tourists on the regional train lines, and the locals know.